# ¿Cómo hacer un organigrama dragabble?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, orgchart

Estoy intentando hacer un organigrama en HTML, CSS y JavaScript. El problema que tengo es que quiero generar mi organigrama con `div`s flotantes e ir construyendo mi organigrama arrastrando esos `div`s. He buscado información y encontré OrgChart.js pero no encuentro cómo adaptarlo con `div`s flotantes.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Organigrama-resultante').orgchart({
    'data': $('#organigrama'),
    'draggable': true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/css/jquery.orgchart.css" />

<ul id="organigrama" style="display:block;">
  <li>Atenea
    <ul>
      <li>Dohko de Libra
        <ul>
          <li>Shiryu</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Camus de Acuario
        <ul>
          <li>Crystal Saint
            <ul>
              <li>Hyoga de Cisne</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Mu de aries
        <ul>
          <li>Kiki</li>
          <li>Prueba</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- en la siguiente etiqueta saldrá el resultado: -->
<div id="Organigrama-resultante">

</div>
```

Comment: Debes compartir lo que has intentado para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Acá hay un ejemplo de un orgChart draggable: view-source:https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/drag-drop.html

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo y eso quiero hacer pero ir agregando los div o valores que no estén en el mapa

Comment: @jor parece que el organigrama ya es draggable. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar con JOrchChart Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo

Comment: @jor ¿cómo lo solucionaste al final?

Comment: encontré una librería que se llama jOrgChart y ya lo tenia echo